# How to organize all namespaces better?

Tags: php, php-7

I am adding in every page manually namespaces, but is there a better way doing it?

```
use James\Art\AutoLoad;
use James\Art\Search;
use James\Art\Binary;
use James\Art\RD\Test;
use James\Art\RD\UTest;
use James\Art\RD\UTest2;
```

Thank You!

Comment: you can group them. using one use only.

Comment: Can you plese show me how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
use James\Art\{
  Autoload,
  Search,
  Binary,
  RD\Test,
  RD\UTest,
  RD\Utest2
};
```

it will only work with PHP7, you can see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.group-use-declarations) for more information.

Comment: Good to note: this is a [new feature added in PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.group-use-declarations). It doesn't work in PHP 5.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few times where I've been using a number of related namespaces - for example as Symfony/Doctrine Entities, or Value Objects, and so to help clarify exactly what a particular class is for, I deliberately don't use the minimal possible name, and instead add the next level up - leading to code like:

```
<?php
namespace xyz;
use xyz\Vo;
use xyz\Entity;
use James\Art;

...

$x = new Vo\Email;
$y = new Vo\Username;
$z = Entity\User;

$auto = Art\AutoLoad;
$search = Art\Search;
```

Having the clarity of what sort of class I'm using, without having to refer back up to the `use` lines, IMHO, makes the code a little more obvious as to what is happening.

If I'm using a several classes within a common namespace, it also has the side-effect of reducing the number of `use` lines required, without making the file headers any more complex to read.